Choose 3 non-adjacent points on a hypercube
I am to find the number of boolean functions of $n$ variables, such that their CDNF of length 3 is their unique DNF.
After using some theorems (if CDNF is unique, then there are no adjacent vectors in the set of unities of a function) I've reduced the task to the following: in how many ways can I choose 3 non-adjacent points on an n-dimensional hypercube?
Calculating that for $n=3$ is straightforward, yielding 8 possible options. However, a general case is a complex problem.
For the first point we have $2^n$ options. For the second point: $2^n - 1 - n$ options. What about the third point?

Please define what a DNF and a CDNF are.

DNF is a disjunctive normal form of a boolean function. CDNF is a canonical disjunctive normal form. You can read about it more here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjunctive_normal_form

The number of ways to choose an ordered triple $(v_1,v_2,v_3)$ of distinct hypercube vertices is $2^n(2^n-1)(2^n-2)$, ignoring the non-adjacency requirement. To factor in the adjacency requirement, we use the principle of inclusion-exclusion.
Let $U$ be the set of all ordered triples of hypercube vertices, so $|U|=2^n(2^n-1)(2^n-2)$. Let $E_{12}$ be the subset of $U$ where $v_1$ is adjacent to $v_2$. This is a bad subset which must be subtracted out. Similarly, let $E_{23}$ be the subset where $v_2$ is adjacent to $v_3$, and $E_{13}$ be the subset where $v_1$ is next to $v_3$. The PIE says that the number of elements of $U$ which are in none of $E_{12},E_{13},$ nor $E_{23}$ is
$$
|U|
-|E_{12}|-|E_{13}|-|E_{23}|\\
+|E_{12}\cap E_{13}|+|E_{12}\cap E_{23}|+|E_{13}\cap E_{23}|
-|E_{12}\cap E_{13}\cap E_{23}|\\
=|U|-3|E_{12}|+3|E_{12}\cap E_{13}|-0.
$$
We already know $|U|$, so we need to find $|E_{12}|$ and $|E_{12}\cap E_{13}|$. We have
$$
|E_{12}|=2^n\cdot n\cdot (2^n-2).
$$
There are $2^n$ choices for $v_1$. Since $v_2$ is adjacent to $v_1$, there are only $n$ choices for $v_2$, as it can be adjacent in any of $n$ directions. There are then $(2^n-2)$ choices for $v_3$. Using similar logic,
$$
|E_{12}\cap E_{13}|=2^n\cdot n\cdot (n-1).
$$
We have shown that the number of ordered triples of three non-adjacent points is
$$
2^n(2^n-1)(2^n-2)-3\cdot 2^n\cdot n\cdot (2^n-2)+3\cdot 2^n\cdot n\cdot (n-1)
$$
However, you wanted to count unordered selections of three vertices. To fix this, divide the above expression by $3!$. The answer to your question is then
$$
\frac{2^n(2^n-1)(2^n-2)-3\cdot 2^n\cdot n\cdot (2^n-2)+3\cdot 2^n\cdot n\cdot (n-1)}{6}
$$
